# How to use "control endpoint" (default endpoint) in client application?

Tags: c, windows, usb, hid, wdk

I have USB HID device, which has only control endpoint. "USB Device Viewer" by Microsoft indicates 0 endpoints as it never counts control endpoints.
I don't know much about this device - it's basically black box to me. All I know is, that it's HID class and it's capable of simple serial communication (there's 1-Wire on "the other end of a cable").
As for HW, there's AVR MCU(not much help there). And as for FW, it uses VID, PID, which doesn't say anything to google (clearly made up).
I red [here](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_5.htm) that after USB device is configured, one can use control endpoint for device specific use.
My question is:
**Is it possible under Windows 7 using WDK to use control endpoint in user space application?**
**If not, is there any other way?**
**If yes, how?**

HidD_GetHidGuid(&guid); doesn't even list my device. Probably due to the fact that device claims to be class 0x00 not only in device descriptor:
*`*bDeviceClass:                      0x00  -> This is an Interface Class Defined Device*`*
but in interface descriptor too:

```
bInterfaceClass:                   0x00
*!*CAUTION:  0 is a Reserved USB Device Interface Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run Wireshark? (Though I believe Wireshark doesn't monitor USB on windows - not sure about that. There are other USB packet sniffers around)

With wireshark you can monitor all communications to the device.

Though I don't know the WDK, I have the impression that many, if not most people use libusb (http://libusb.info/). There is a Windows version which can run on both 32 and 64-bit versions. This library is fairly easy to use, and has access to all endpoints.

Comment: I was not aware that Wireshark can work with USB raw communication. Thank you for pointing that out. But it it doesn't help me with my question. My question is more WDK related.